# how to make mysql multiple column index for fast execution

Tags: mysql

I have a query for which i want to apply index .Query is

```
select * from table where (id1='12' AND id2='17') OR (id1='17' AND id2='12');
```

Now I tried to apply index with (id1,id2) but explain query showed me "ALL" for "type"
when i tried (id2,id1) or id1 and id2 still response was same. so how to index on id1 and id2 to handle above query.

```
mysql> explain select * from bothTable where (id1=12 and id2=17) OR (id1=17 and id2=12);
+----+-------------+------------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table            | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+------------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | bothTable | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |   67 | Using where |
+----+-------------+------------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> create index index_id1 ON bothTable (id1,id2);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> explain select * from bothTable where (id1=12 and id2=17) OR (id1=17 and id2=12);
+----+-------------+------------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table            | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+------------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | bothTable | ALL  | index_id1     | NULL | NULL    | NULL |   67 | Using where |
+----+-------------+------------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

with union it is giving me below output :

```
+----+--------------+------------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type  | table            | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra       |
+----+--------------+------------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY      | bothTable | ALL  | index_id1     | NULL | NULL    | NULL |   67 | Using where |
|  2 | UNION        | bothTable | ALL  | index_id1     | NULL | NULL    | NULL |   67 | Using where |
| NULL | UNION RESULT | <union1,2>       | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | NULL |             |
+----+--------------+------------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
create index id1_id2 on table(id1, id2);
```

also, do not put '' around your integers if your id1 and id2 columns are integer columns,  instead try this:

```
select * from table where (id1=12 AND id2=17) OR (id1=17 AND id2=12);
```

example:

```
mysql> explain select * from ff where (id1 = '12' and id2 = '17') or (id1 = '17' and id2 = '12');
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | ff    | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |    7 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> create index id1_id2 on ff(id1,id2);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.15 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> explain select * from ff where (id1 = 12 and id2 = 17) or (id1 = 17 and id2 = 12);
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | ff    | index | id1_id2       | id1_id2 | 10      | NULL |    7 | Using where; Using index |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+--------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

**edit**
since that still doesnt seem to be working, try this one out:

```
explain 
select * from ff where (id1 = 12 and id2 = 17)
union
select * from ff where (id1 = 17 and id2 = 12);
```

Comment: sorry for typo mistake . my id column data type is int. and see above updated question i already made this index , but it didn give me what i wanted.dnt know why

Comment: well it sees the key in your updated post, but it doesn't choose to use it. you can try forcing it with `select * from bothtable force index(index_id1) where .... ` also, try it with only one of the conditions, not both with the or

Comment: if i write force index query with explain then still it shows me same like earlier output, why?  and how come it is not able to use this index ?

Comment: its most likely the or condition in that case, try breaking it into a union instead. i updated the answer with that example

Comment: see updated question, I mentioned in question what i got as output so i think it is still unable to use it

Comment: how many other fields are in each row? try just selecting id1 or id2 and see if it makes a difference. i get wildly different explain results to you on my little test here - maybe this is going to come down to mysql version

Comment: hey , that was my silly mistake . datatype of id1, id2 was varchar which i changed to id and it started giving me range. Thanks for help. Please tell me one more thing I need to write clause (id1=12 or id2=12) how to do that. i have applied (id1,id2) index and id2 index but no use.

Comment: you'd need a single index on id2 as (id1, id2) does not cover id2 alone

Comment: I did what you said in comment earlier but it is still giving me ALL for TYPE .
| id | select_type | table            | type | possible_keys       | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+------------------+------+---------------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | bothTables | ALL  | index_id4,index_id5 | NULL | NULL    | NULL |   69 | Using where |
+----+-------------+------------------+------+---------------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

Comment: as with the above one, try breaking it into a union instead of using or